# Identifying x, y coordinates in the same row and are closest to 1000, 2000 respectively

Tags: python, pandas, lidar

I have a pandas dataframe with x,y columns containing coordinates. These coordinates are ground lidar point cloud coordinates. I would like to find the scan position coordinate of x closest to 1000 and y coordinate closest to 2000 ( original scan position which was set up to X = 1000, Y = 2000 during the scanning). Here is the example data (h - height, i - intensity):

```
         x          y         h      i
0   1088.347856 1877.719005 94.869  0.0

1   1083.338856 1886.024105 95.404  2566.0

2   1078.758756 1890.846705 93.314  0.0

3   1078.781556 1890.810205 93.479  257.0

4   1078.791256 1890.804605 93.559  1026.0

5   1078.804756 1890.778805 93.729  1540.0

6   1078.900756 1890.792905 94.324  1283.0

7   1078.900756 1890.792905 94.579  0.0

8   1078.919556 1890.771805 94.749  513.0

9   1078.892856 1890.663205 95.934  770.0

10  1078.841956 1890.731405 95.259  1026.0
```

I did so far, tried to find closest coordinates:

```
for x_min in df['x']:
for y_min in df['y']:
    x_min = min(df.iloc[:,0], key=lambda x:abs(x-1000))
    y_min = min(df.iloc[:,1], key=lambda y:abs(y-2000))
```

> This gave me around 100 X,Y values closest to 1000 and 2000. Now I want to find index values of these numbers.

```
    item_index_x = np.where(df.iloc[:,0]==x_min)
    item_index_y = np.where(df.iloc[:,1]==y_min)
```

> Here I tried to find if there are any X,Y coordinates in the same row, not sure if below code is correct.
>           if item_index_x == item_index_y:
>               print(item_index_x)
>               print(item_index_y)

Unfortunately, it didn't give any coordinate closest to 1000, 2000 in the same row. But it found coordinates with X closest to 1000 and Y closest to 2000 independently, meaning for example X = 1000.00001 but Y = 1998.0023. I was wondering if there is anyone who can help me.

Comment: would you like show us some sample data ?

Comment: Thanks @Wen, example data has been added.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're asking for, it seems like the relative distance could be represented by the sum of the two differences:

```
df['dist'] = abs(df['x']-1000) + abs(df['y']-2000)
```

And then your closest X,Y pairs would be based on the smallest distance:

```
df.nsmallest(5, "dist")  # return the 5 closest X,Y pairs
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @clockwatcher. This is exactly what I wanted, very elegant solution.